# Open physical drive. Windows

Tags: c++, windows

I try open physical drive like

```
ofstream * _fileWriter->open(_destPath, std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::binary);
```

_destPath = \\.\PhysicalDrive1
But, when i try do

```
if (!(_fileWriter->is_open()))
    return false;
```

It return false

Comment: I always thought, you can just open files directly with a fstream class. Is _fileWriter a pointer ?

Comment: Yes, _fileWriter is a pointer

Comment: does _fileWriter points to valid ofstream?

Comment: Yes. When i try use ifstream to open _destPath. Ifstream is ok, but when i use ofstream it`s dont open drive

Comment: Try standard `open` or `fopen` functions from `stdio.h`.

Comment: An answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2616378/cant-write-to-physical-drive-in-win-7) suggests it may be due to a new-ish system protection feature. Is the drive mounted? [This document](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/100027) says *You must use both the CreateFile() FILE_SHARE_READ and FILE_SHARE_WRITE flags to gain access to the drive.* so maybe ostream is not passing the correct flags to the underlying API?

Comment: Using the language wrappers to low level OS access is usually a bad idea. Not that your code is going to be portable anyway...

Answer (score 4):

You have to run the program with elevated access.

Request `GENERIC_READ` / `GENERIC_WRITE`

```
hdrive = CreateFile(L"\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive0", GENERIC_READ,
    FILE_SHARE_READ, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
```

If you just want to get disk information, you can open the disk with no read/write access, the code below shouldn't need elevated access:

```
HANDLE hdrive;
hdrive = CreateFile(L"\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive0", 0, 
    FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
if (hdrive == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    cout << "error " << GetLastError() << endl;
    return 0;
}

cout << "open" << endl;
CloseHandle(hdrive);
```